# How can I use "First Name" entered by user and use it as personalisation in a multi-step form questions?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

This is a simple HTML structure of a multi-step form. I want to use the first name of user as personalisation in form section `<p>`.

For say if someone enters their name as "Jack" and then clicks on next button.... then in the next section the `<p>` will read as "Jack, What's your age?" and then the final section's `<p>` will be "Are you good Jack?"

```html
<form action="">
  <div class="section1">
    <input type="text" placeholder="First Name">
    <button class="next-btn">Next</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="section2">
    <p>[First Name], What's your age?</p>
    <input type="number" class="age" placeholder="Your Age">
    <button class="next-btn">Next</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="section3">
    <p>Are you doing good [First Name]?</p>
    <input type="text" class="good" placeholder="Yes or No ?">
    <button class="submit">submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

I am new to JS. So am not able to understand how to do this. Looking forward to some assistance, please.

Comment: When clicking next, trigger a JS function to save the input value and set it as content to the target element.

Comment: @Michael M... Is it not a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083709/how-to-make-button-active-after-input-field-is-filled-in-multi-step-forms ??? Check at the answer of Michael Frankie!

Comment: @tatactic Not really, I don't think so. They are kind of different questions, my answers just look similar. I first wrote an answer here, then Frankie asked me to answer over there too, so I extended my answer given the new criteria. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To use the first name in later stages of the form, create empty `<span>`s whose `.textContent` can be edited with JS.

Then, to get multistage functionality, you can create a CSS utility class `hidden` to hide everything except the first stage. Then, you can add event handlers for each of the "Next" buttons that will stop the default event (which is submitting the form), and optionally do some stuff (like setting some `<span>`'s `.textContent` with the value of an input), then toggle off the `hidden` class on the next section to show it. Like this:

```js
document.querySelector('#next1').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const firstName = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
  document.querySelectorAll('.firstName').forEach(el => el.textContent = firstName);
  document.querySelector('#section1').classList.toggle('hidden');
  document.querySelector('#section2').classList.toggle('hidden');
});

document.querySelector('#next2').addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  document.querySelector('#section2').classList.toggle('hidden');
  document.querySelector('#section3').classList.toggle('hidden');
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" action="">
  <div id="section1">
    <input type="text" id="firstName" placeholder="First Name">
    <button id="next1">Next</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="section2" class="hidden">
    <p><span class="firstName"></span>, What's your age?</p>
    <input type="number" class="age" placeholder="Your Age">
    <button id="next2">Next</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div id="section3" class="hidden">
    <p>Are you doing good <span class="firstName"></span>?</p>
    <input type="text" class="good" placeholder="Yes or No ?">
    <button class="submit">submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. But in your code, on clicking on next step, the next step displays but the previous step doesn't get hide. What's the fix for that?

Comment: @Frankie I've just edited my answer to fix that. It should work now. Can you try again?

Comment: @Frankie If my answer solves your issue, then you can upvote/accept it to indicate to others that it worked for you.

Comment: Can you also please edit your code so that the button is set disabled until input is filled or radio checked. I've trying to do so but if you can do it here, it really helps.

Comment: @Frankie I feel that doing that might stray away from the original question a bit. On Stack Overflow, questions should be specific to one problem. However, I see [you have another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76083709/how-to-make-button-active-after-input-field-is-filled-in-multi-step-forms) for this same problem. I'll try to answer it over there.

Comment: I was going through your JS code and trying to understand as I mentioned I'm new to JS. So what is "e =>" ?

Comment: @Frankie That's an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). In most cases, it's just a shorter way of writing a function. In this case, the function takes one parameter `e` that is an [`Event` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event).

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this, i hope it helps you!

```js
    var name;

    function triggerSection2() {
        document.getElementById("section1").style.display = "none"; //make the first section invisible

        name = document.getElementById("NameInput").value; //save the Name to an public variable
        document.getElementById("section2Text").innerHTML = name + ", What's your age?"; //change the innerHTML (text) of the "p" tag at the second section

        document.getElementById("section2").style.display = "block"; //make the second section visible
    }

    function triggerSection3() {
        document.getElementById("section2").style.display = "none"; //make the second section invisible

        document.getElementById("section3Text").innerHTML = "Are you doing good " + name + "?"; //change the text of the "p" tag at the third section

        document.getElementById("section3").style.display = "block"; //make the third section visible
    }
```

```html
<form action="">
    <div class="section1" id="section1"> <!--need an id to call the element in js-->
        <input type="text" id="NameInput" placeholder="First Name"> <!--need an id to call the element in js-->
        <button class="next-btn" type="button" onclick="triggerSection2()">Next</button> <!--clearify the type="button" so the page don't reload on press and call an js function on click-->
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="display: none" class="section2" id="section2"> <!--need an id to call the element in js-->
        <p id="section2Text"></p> <!--need an id to call the element in js, Text will be added by js-->
        <input type="number" class="age" placeholder="Your Age">
        <button class="next-btn" type="button" onclick="triggerSection3()">Next</button> <!--clearify the type="button" so the page don't reload on press and call an js function on click-->
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="display: none" id="section3" class="section3"> <!--need an id to call the element in js-->
        <p id="section3Text"></p> <!--need an id to call the element in js, text will be added by js-->
        <input type="text" class="good" placeholder="Yes or No ?" >
        <input type="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Using `onclick` attributes for event handlers isn't best practice these days. It's better to use `.addEventListener()` from your JS.

Comment: Good answers include some explanation of the code

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).